# How I can assign sdc/sdd to my usb drives

Tags: kernel

I am having strange problem. Can't find any solution.

Using Ubuntu 12.04. My hard disk drive assigned as sda. If I plug-in any USB drive, it automatically assigned as sdb. That's fine.

But after reboot, USB drives assigned as sda and hard disk drive shows as sdb. So my fstab mount point showing error on start.

I would like to make any USB drive, goes after hard drive - as usually been in Windows.

Please, anyone help me. I am struggling at this point.

Thanking you in advance.

Raihan

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest you do two things,

1. Use `UUID`s instead of `/dev/sd*` in your `fstab` so that it is not messed up.
2. Get you started with `udev` so you can make your thumb drives appear as `/dev/whatever`

#### Section 1.

Ensure that all the devices listed in your `fstab` are plugged into the system. Wait a few seconds and then type

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

This will give you something that looks like the following:total 0

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 4e36d61c-e6f4-4a1a-b760-45ee5a76e141 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 52a04f5d-2576-48d1-8340-544cc24e0fcd -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 55a1d85d-e5f5-416e-adf7-3aed3e6309f1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 5c8c3b19-5550-4411-8fc3-692aa94bb4af -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 8bfea793-5cb2-480c-a4e3-2b3c331463bb -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 a369bc5e-3bf0-454b-b04d-2936e343e959 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 e57e2838-2c56-43c3-b4b8-de0743c67181 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 24 20:19 f7772f0f-19d7-4ced-b0a0-b543e4bd54fe -> ../../dm-2
```

Now look up what you have in your `fstab`. Everywhere you have something like `/dev/sdc1` I want you to replace it with something like `UUID=55a1d85d-e5f5-416e-adf7-3aed3e6309f1`. What this will do is tell `mount` to use the `UUID` to identify a device instead of it's location under `/dev`. These `UUID` are unique and last the lifetime of the filesystem.

#### Section 2.

`udev` is the service that is responsible for placing block devices (and other devices) under `/dev` in Ubuntu. You can actually write your own rules for `udev` that instruct it to make symlinks under `/dev` in a consistent way. The way `udev` works is that everytime a device is attached it scans a long list of rules and takes the actions specified by any that match. The matching is done by inspecting a bunch of parameters of the device such as, `UUID`, port it is plugged into, PCI address, etc. So you can identify your thumb drive by the filesystem's `UUID` and have a rule to map that to `/dev/myThumbDrive` and use `/dev/myThumbDrive` anywhere you would normally use `/dev/sda1` (for example).

You can find a list of attributes to identify your drive with by typing

```
udevadm info -n /dev/sde --attribute-walk

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sde/sde1':
  KERNEL=="sde1"
  SUBSYSTEM=="block"
  DRIVER==""
  ATTR{partition}=="1"
  ATTR{start}=="1"
  ATTR{size}=="24242084"
  ATTR{ro}=="0"
  ...

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sde':
 KERNELS=="sde"
 SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
 DRIVERS==""
 ATTRS{range}=="16"
 ATTRS{ext_range}=="256"
 ATTRS{removable}=="1"
 ATTRS{ro}=="0"
 ATTRS{size}=="31250432"
 ATTRS{alignment_offset}=="0"
 ATTRS{discard_alignment}=="0"
 ATTRS{capability}=="51"
 ...

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0':
 KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"
 SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
 DRIVERS=="sd"
 ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
 ATTRS{type}=="0"
 ATTRS{scsi_level}=="3"
 ATTRS{vendor}=="SanDisk "
 ATTRS{model}=="Cruzer          "
 ATTRS{rev}=="1.00"
 ...

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0':
 ....

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/host6':
 ....

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0':
 ...
 SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
 DRIVERS=="usb-storage"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8/8-1':
 ....
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="0781"
 ATTRS{idProduct}=="5530"
 ....
 ATTRS{manufacturer}=="SanDisk"
 ATTRS{product}=="Cruzer"
 ATTRS{serial}=="20043513610A15E24E49" 

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb8':
 ....

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0':
 ....

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2':
 ....

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
 ....
```

And then you can create a rule that looks something like this:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="USB 2.0 Storage Device", SYMLINK+="myThumbDrive%n"
```

So that `/dev/myThumbDrive1` can be used instead of `/dev/sd[a-z]1`

#### Alternate Method

This is too much typing of UUID's for my taste. Maybe it will be easier for you.

http://scnr.net/blog/index.php/archives/132